# Declaretheoremstyle headpostspace = \newline + indent?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, theorems, thmtools

I am having problems trying in declaring a theorem style. I would like the first row of the definition to be on a new line with the normal indent. If I try to add `\par` instead of `\newline` for `postheadspace`, I am getting error. Also `postheadhook` doesn't seem to work.

Thank you in advance :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsbook}

\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\scshape\bfseries, 
headindent = \parindent,
postheadhook = {\hspace{0mm}\newline},
postheadspace = \newline, 
spaceabove = 0.5cm, 
spacebelow = 0.5cm]{mydef}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{mydef}

\newtheorem{Definition}[Theorem]{Definition}
\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}
This is a very long definition which i want to start with indent on the next row instead of from the beggining

Like this
\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your style to properly apply, you need to use `\declaretheorem` to define your structure and not `\newtheorem`. Using `postheadhook = {\hspace*{\parindent}}` you'll get the desired output (I left the `Theorem` structure with `\newtheorem` since apparently it shouldn't have the `mydef` style; if you want to apply this style for `Theorem`, please use `\declaretheorem` instead; if you don't wnat the indentation for the head, delete the line `headindent = \parindent`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\scshape\bfseries, 
headindent = \parindent,
postheadhook = {\hspace*{\parindent}},
postheadspace = \newline, 
spaceabove = 0.5cm, 
spacebelow = 0.5cm]{mydef}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\declaretheorem[style=mydef,numberlike=Theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}
This is a very long definition which will start with indent on the next row instead of from the beginning.

Like this
\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]